# I have a 24 gig RAM pc with intel Xeon and still get 3 fps on minecraft

Tags: minecraft

I tried allocating 20 gigs to minecraft but it only uses about 1.

Comment: What graphics hardware are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The FPS (frames per second) rate is far more dependent on the speed of the GPU (Graphics Processing Unit) than the CPU (the Central Processing Unit, your Xeon) or the size of your RAM. Therefore, if you want better graphical performance, please consider a new video card, after verifying you have the best driver for your existing graphics adapter. Considering what most Xeons are used for (servers), the graphics adapter could be *sub-optimal*.

Comment: He doesn't need a new video card, he just needs to get the correct driver working for the one he has.  No card with a working driver can be *that* slow.

Comment: Not sure about that. Older P4 based Xeons might be able to use 24GB and still have very slow  on-board graphics. But that is reaching on my part. I think you are right for 99% of the cases.

@OP:

First of all. Please post a bit more information than just "
I tried allocating 20 gigs to minecraft but it only uses about 1"

Secondly, consider what you just wrote. Either it is limited because it want more RAM and you failed to *successfully* assign it, or it has much more RAM than it can use and something else limits the speed.